# HTML::SimpleLinkExtor is changing Ç to %C7 on a link

Tags: html, perl, selenium

I've been using HTML::SimpleLinkExtor to extract links from this page: http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/authorIndex/AUTHOR_index.html  Although it works great for everyting, it doesn't when one link has 'Ç' as a character.  What it does it changes it to %C7.  Therefore when I use the link in the rest of my program I get a code 404 error.  Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::SimpleLinkExtor;
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
use Test::More "no_plan"; #tests => 37; #
#use Test::Exception;


Test::More->builder->output ('result.txt');
Test::More->builder->failure_output ('errors.txt');

my $base = "http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/authorIndex/AUTHOR_index.html";

my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host        => "localhost", 
                                    port        =>  4444, 
                                    browser     => "*firefox", 
                                    browser_url => "http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/" );


################################################
my  $extor = HTML::SimpleLinkExtor->new($base);
    $extor->parse_url($base);           
my  @all_links   = $extor->a;           
################################################


$sel->start();

            $sel->open_ok($base);

            $sel->open_ok($_) foreach (@all_links);

$sel->stop();
```

As well, are there any ideas how I can implement the click() function with the extracted links .

Thanks

Comment: Note: The server expects the string to be UTF-8 encoded, so `http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/authorIndex/AUTHOR_%C3%87.html`. Can't look into how to make that happen.

Comment: hum, the page is encoded using iso-8859-1, so technically, the URL in the page is equivalent to `AUTHOR_%C7.html`.

Comment: So I guess the solution would involve decoding the URL using iso-8859-1 and re-encoding it using UTF-8.

Comment: @ikegami According to [Wikipedia: Percent-Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) URIs should always use UTF-8 for percent encoding.  That was added to RFC 3986 in january 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That webpage gets served in latin1 encoding and thus it encodes Ç as byte 0xC7.  Nonetheless, HTML::SimpleLinkExtor *should* be clever enough to convert this to UTF-8 for the link, since that's pretty much standard.  However it doesn't do so.  In [its source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BDFOY/HTML-SimpleLinkExtor-1.25/lib/HTML/SimpleLinkExtor.pm) it says:

```
sub parse_url {
    my $data = $_[0]->ua->get( $_[1] )->content;
    return unless $data;
    $_[0]->parse( $data );
}
```

The mistake here is that it should use **->decoded_content** instead of **->content** in order to properly do encoding conversion.  You might want to file a bug report for HTML::SimpleLinkExtor.  In the mean time you could try to write an own method to replace this broken one.

**EDIT:** This might work (untested):

```
# replace this:
$extor->parse_url($base);           

# with this:
my $data = $extor->ua->get($base)->decoded_content;
if (defined $data) {
    $extor->parse($data);
}
```

Comment: Nice one jlh.  It's now http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/authorIndex/AUTHOR_%C3%87.html and doesn't show an error when clicked.